# Error "Cannot use object as array" when trying to set content of column as variable

Tags: php, mysql

I use IDs rather than usernames as I find them easier to handle, and as a result I need to access the database first when I want to display a username.

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users.users WHERE id = $userid";
$user = $pdo->query($sql);
$username = $user['name'];
```

But when doing so I get an error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array`. In theory my code should set `$userid` as the ID of the currently logged in user, select the corresponding row in `users.users` and set `$username` as the name column, with which I can work then. How can I convert the PDOStatement to be usable?

Comment: I think you should read the docu to get knowledge about the basics of database queries and later about SQL injection.

Comment: To clarify, I'm very well aware my code is vulnerable to SQL injection. However the website isn't online yet, and while I'm still learning I don't see a point in more advanced, securer methods when I'm still not comfortable with the basics. Thanks for pointing out though, I'll remove the risk before putting the site up on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDO::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) returns a [`PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object, to get the values from it you need to perform a [`fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users.users WHERE id = $userid";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$username = $user['name'];
```